# xcolor `table' options clears part of the hhline command output

Tags: tables, colortbl, hhline

When I use `table` option for xcolor package or use `colortbl` package, it clears part of the hhline (red border in below picture)! How can I fix this problem? When I remove `table` option, the output is true; but I need it.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[table,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hhline}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{||l||l||}
\hhline{|t:=:tb:=:t|}
\multicolumn{2}{||c||}{\thead{Text 1}} \\
\hhline{|:=:tb:=:|}
\multicolumn{2}{||c||}{\thead{Text 2}} \\

\hhline{|:=:t:=:|}
\thead{\textbf{Text 3}} & \thead{\textbf{Text 4}} \\
\hhline{|:=::=:|}
Text 5 & Text 6 \\
\hhline{|b:=:b:=:b|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must confess that I don't understand why you employ `\hhline{|t:=:tb:=:t|}` and `\hhline{|:=:tb:=:|}`, respectively, for the first two instances of `\hhline`. For sure, if you run `\hhline{|t:==:t|}` and `\hhline{|:==:|}`, respectively, the issue you've encountered doesn't arise, whether or not `xcolor` is loaded with the option `table` (or, equivalently, if the `tblcolor` package is loaded).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell,hhline}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{||l||l||}
\hhline{|t:==:t|} % not '\hhline{|t:=:tb:=:t|}'
\multicolumn{2}{||c||}{\thead{Text 1}} \\
\hhline{|:==:|}   % not '\hhline{|:=:tb:=:|}'
\multicolumn{2}{||c||}{\thead{Text 2}} \\
\hhline{|:=:t:=:|}
\thead{\textbf{Text 3}} & \thead{\textbf{Text 4}} \\
\hhline{|:=::=:|}
Text 5 & Text 6 \\
\hhline{|b:=:b:=:b|}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For information, here is a way to construct that table with `nicematrix` (≥ 6.24 of 2023-09-28).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc}
  \Block{1-2}{Text 1} \\
  \Block{1-2}{Text 2} \\
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}
  Text 3 & Text 4 \\
  Text 5 & Text 6 
\CodeAfter
  \TikzEveryCell{offset=1pt,draw}
  \tikz \draw ([xshift=-1pt,yshift=1pt]1-|1) rectangle ([xshift=1pt,yshift=-1pt]last-|last) ;
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]